# VB.Net WinForms Switching Views Causes Scrollbar to move/focus on wrong spot

Tags: vb.net, focus, scrollbar, windows-forms-designer

I'm going thru some code at work for a Screen "Acounts Detail" that has a Address TextBox field, it's very similiar to a VB.Net WindowsForm but its my companies own proprietary design view. Anywho, when you type in the address box, and get it to Focus, if you switch to a different view via the Left hand vertical toolbar, say to the "Contacts" or "Opportunities" views, when you return to the "Account Detail" view, the scroll bar has moved to the bottom of the page, and it hides the address and structure TextBoxes/ListViews. I have a photo below showing the Account Details view (zipcode highlighted in yellow) and then upon switching to another view (i.e. Contacts or Opportunities), you can see the scrollbar has moved down.

I'm just looking for some advice where to look in the code, the main logic is in a VB file called "Screenlogic" and there is only a few Focus() methods in there, which my original assumption was that it was focusing on something below, like "Agency Defined Categories", however, I don't see anything being highlighted or focused, so it makes me think something else is happening (could it be focusing something NOT on in that .vb file causing the scrollbar to move down trying to find something non existant?)

I'm somewhat new to VB.Net/WindowsForms and I'm new to this company so I'll take any advice debugging. I've attached some processes and am using Visual Studio debugger to step thru the code, but haven't found anything that meaningful so far.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your company should hire a developer to work on their proprietary software.

Comment: Oh, I'm just an intern. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? The designer tool just has different names for the layout of the UI - all the logic should be the same, which is why I came here to stack overflow to see if someone encountered a similar bug for guidance.